# Combining Pseudo-classes in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

If I need selected text in a hovered link be red, could I use the following code in CSS style?

```
.abc:hover:selection{color:red}
```

and

```
<a href="123" class="abc">4567890</a>
```

Would that link, when I select part of it, become red colored when I hover it and is this correct syntax for such pseudo-classes combining?

Comment: @David Thomas: I should know is it correct way or not

Comment: When in doubt, validate.  If it doesn't validate, then it's clearly wrong.

Comment: @cimmanon: it's much simple to ask =)

Comment: It's simpler to ask SO than to validate?  Makes no sense to me.

Comment: This is one of those rare times I have to downvote the question because when prompted to test the asker outright refuses to do so, and *yet* I have to post my own answer anyway and downvote the existing answer because it is wrong.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can combine pseudo-classes in any order.

Except in this case, `::selection` is not a pseudo-class, it's a pseudo-element that's not part of CSS1 or CSS2, or any current spec for that matter. And this is where the term "pseudo-selector" falls short, because they're two completely different things.

The correct syntax is a single colon for `:hover` and double colons for `::selection`, and unlike pseudo-classes, pseudo-elements must always come last:

```
.abc:hover::selection{color:red}
```

And even then, because of the way `::selection` works (or doesn't), it's not guaranteed to actually have an effect in browsers.

Comment: But it could be combined amd it is correct way. Thats what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

```
 .container:nth-last-child(2):not(:first-child) {
    background-color: red;
 }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation - code only answers are not necessarily helpful. How does this answer the question?