# Combining pseudo element and pseudo class won't work

Tags: css, combinations

I try to combine a pseudo element `:before` and a pseudo class `:nth-child(2)` in my `#breadcrumbs` section in my site.

I tried to use:

```
#breadcrumbs li:before:nth-child(2) {content: "> "}
#breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2):before {content: "> "}
```

Either didn't work, so I tried to read about it and found this in Google:

[Combining Pseudo-selectors in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455753/combining-pseudo-selectors-in-css)

According to the answer in that discussion, also tried adding two colons before the second pseudo-selector, `nth-child(2)`, like this:

```
#breadcrumbs li:before::nth-child(2) {content: "> "}
```

Sadly none of these 3 examples work.

I should note that when I remove the :nth-child(2) or ::nth-child(2), and keeps only with :before, the CSS command `#breadcrumbs li:before {content: "> "}` works just fine.

Note:

I use this [Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/basic) (you could download the 8.x.x version to examine CSS); I personally add my custom css in a custom file, last in the CSS hierarchy determined by the libraries.yml file.

Yet, these are the only might-be relevant code pieces I found inside the core CSS files:

```
.breadcrumb li {list-style-type: none; display: inline-block}

#header, #footer, .mission, .breadcrumb, .node {clear: both}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the CSS code `#breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2)::before {content: ">"}` was fine, and the problem was due to id-class clashing in the html.twig template files.

What solved the issue was changing in breadcrumb.html.twig, from:

```
{% if breadcrumb %}
  <nav class="breadcrumb" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="system-breadcrumb">
    <h2 id="system-breadcrumb" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Breadcrumb'|t }}</h2>
```

To:

```
{% if breadcrumb %}
  <nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="system-breadcrumb">
    <h2{{ 'Breadcrumb'|t }}</h2>
```

Now, the `#breadcrumbs` id directives, don't clash with either these of `.breadcrumb` class, or `#system-breadcrumb` id.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, please look at this demo

```css
#breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: ">";
}
```

```html
<ul id="breadcrumbs">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

I think you have a typo in your CSS. Please make this change:

```
#breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2):before {content: "> "}
```

into

```
#breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2)::before {content: "> "}
```

I believe you need two colons for `before` in CSS, read this related question: [Why are there two colons here? span::before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400323/why-are-there-two-colons-here-spanbefore)

Comment: The first example you gave added > sign before both li units, and not only before the second one (nth-child(2))... The second example putting the before last with 2 colos - Don't work for me in my theme.

Comment: @Benia I have updated the JSFiddle to use `:nth-child(2)::before`. Please take a look. Could you post more CSS from your theme? It seems it should be working.

Comment: @Benia in your update, the CSS code references `.breadcrumb` but the original post references `#breadcrumbs`; could it be you need to change one to be either referencing the ID or the class?